# Find lines with the same columns' pairs in one file

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk

Let's say I have this tab-delimited file

```
id1 term1 term2
id2 term1 term2
id3 tern2 term3
```

What I want to do is to count the number of the same column2 column3 occurrences alongside the IDs they refer to.

So the new tab-delimited file will look like this:

```
term1 term2 2 id1,id2
term2 term3 1 id3
```

I have tried this one-liner, which is the closest I have come to the desired solution

```
awk '{count[$2,$3]++;} END {for (word in count) printf("%s\t%s\n", word,count[word])}'
```

But what I get is this:

```
term1 term2 2
term2 term3 1
```

and between the terms a rectangle.

Any ideas with Perl or awk or anything else would be lovely.

At first I thought Perl would be better but a friend of me suggested awk. It was my first time with awk.

Comment: *"At first I thought Perl would be better but a friend of me suggested awk. It was my first time with awk."* Perl will do everything that awk can, with the exception that it is tougher to write terse one-liners in Perl. You should stick with what you know. Anyone who recommends awk over Perl is a fan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution does as you ask

The array `@pairs` only purpose is to retain the order of the input data. If that isn't necessary then the code can be reduced substantially

I have assumed that given pair of column 2 / column 3 values may appear more than once with the same ID. That means I had to count the occurrences of the pair separately from accumulating the related IDs. If that isn't true then the count is simply the number of IDs for each pair

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %pairs;
my @pairs;

while ( <> ) {

    chomp;
    my ($id, $pair) = split "\t", $_, 2;

    push @pairs, $pair unless $pairs{$pair};

    ++$pairs{$pair}{count};
    $pairs{$pair}{ids}{$id} = 1;
}

for my $pair ( @pairs ) {
    my ($n, $ids) = @{ $pairs{$pair} }{qw/ count ids /};
    say join "\t", $pair, $n, join(',', keys %$ids);
}
```

### output

```
term1 term2 2   id1,id2
tern2 term3 1   id3
```

Comment: One up for showing an implementation in Perl. You are right, *a friend told that* is not a reason to choose `awk` over `perl`. A reason to use `awk` is that such algorithms can be pretty nicely and shortly expressed in `awk` and it is `damn!` fast.

Comment: Short algorithms aren't a virtue

Comment: @Sobrique is correct. Conciseness is a virtue, not brevity alone.

Comment: Hmm. If you care about 80 chars per line in code files, often a few chars can make the difference. However, I would not say that is *the* rule over all, of course. For example this problem is not a one liner at all so it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Wow thanks! It is even more than i asked for!

The only thing that i am curious are these:

`$pairs{$pair}{count}`

i understand what you are doing, and that is works, but is this normal?
I mean can you do such things with hash tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -f script.awk input.file
```

Where *script.awk* looks like this:

```
{
    # Select and count the terms combination
    terms=$2" "$3
    count[terms]++

    # Concatenate ids by `,` - except if it
    # is the first occurrence
    ids[terms]=ids[terms] ? ids[terms]","$1 : $1
}
END{
    # At the end print the desired results
    for(terms in count){
        print terms,count[terms],ids[terms]
    }
}
```

Comment: This ignores the possibility that an ID may repeat for a given data pair

Comment: @Borodin An *id* is usually unique. That's the purpose.

Comment: Yes, an ID should be unique for each record in a set of data. But we have no knowledge of the structure of this data and, unless every record consists only of the two columns shown, it may well be that IDs are duplicated in this subset

Comment: Well, if this should really matter, we could simply add a conditional before adding the id to `ids` and check if it has already been added. But the question does not reflect that atm.

Comment: That would fail if one of the first terms evaluated to zero, and the unparenthesized ternary expression could cause a syntax error on some awks and there's a little redundancy. Use `ids[terms]=(terms in ids ? ids[terms]"," : "") $1`.

Comment: @EdMorton Your suggestion looks nice. Let me play around with that tomorrow and possibly add that. I'm afk for today...

Answer (score 1):

WIth GNU awk for true 2D arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ ids[$2 FS $3][$1] }
END {
    for (key in ids) {
        printf "%s\t%s", key, length(ids[key])
        sep = OFS
        for (i in ids[key]) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, i
            sep = ","
        }
        print ""
    }
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
tern2   term3   1       id3
term1   term2   2       id1,id2
```